# Dapper read non default types

Tags: dapper, npgsql

Is it possible with Dapper to read a non default type that is implemented by the `NpgsqlDataReader`?

Npgsql implements multiple types for some postgresql types: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html

> The default type is returned when using NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(), NpgsqlDataReader.GetValue() and similar methods.

> You can read as other types by calling `NpgsqlDataReader.GetFieldValue<T>()`.

Is there any way to force Dapper to call `GetFieldValue<T>` internally?

I tried registering a `SqlMapper` but when I register it for a non default type still the default type is passed into the `Parse(object)` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible at the moment: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/1644